# ASP.Net MVC Dashboard View. Where to perform aggregations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dashboard

I have read a few other stackoverflow posts regarding dashboard setup in a view, but I am still struggling a bit. I have one master query that is returning a detailed view of my data, since I only want to hit the database once. So I have a Controller Action called `GetEmployeeInfo()` that returns a `IEnumerable<EmployeeBase>` model class. I want to be able to take this class and break it apart into different divs in a view. For example, I would have three divs on top of the View aggregating row count by employee category and 2 divs on the botton that shows the detailed table. Can this be accomplished strictly through one view by setting up conditional/aggregate statements all over or do I use partial views or something else. Or is using one controller action a problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I generally think of a dashboard as several small views mashed together.  In that scenario one approach would be to use partial views, each with its own controller action.

Comment: thank you. Would that mean to hit the database for every grouping or run the query and save the data in a file and grab it there

Comment: Please don't save the data in a file... why not have a single controller method that returns your data as JSON and simply use JavaScript on the client to construct the statistics you require from the dataset?

Comment: Another alternative is to have your Dashboard view strongly typed to a View Model like "DashboardViewModel" which is composed of different collections which correspond to the data needed for each sub-part. This would also put the aggregation logic to the server-side rather than on the client in JS. You could even have partial views included, each of which corresponds to a sub-part and a collection of data in your View Model. It's good practice to have your view model directly correlate to the data needed by your view

Answer (score 1):

I used the answer from [Pat Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1991312/pat-burke) (see comments under my question. I posted it below as well). I created one base class and one partial view for my employee categories that has all the properties I needed. I did the same for my detail portion. Then I created the `DashboardViewModel` which had 3 `IEnumerable<EmployeeCategoryBase>` properties as well as 2 `IEnumerable<EmployeeDetailInfo>` properties. Then I created a strongly typed `DashboardViewModel` view with 5 divs that used `@{Html.RenderPartial(ViewName,model.property);}`

> Another alternative is to have your Dashboard view strongly typed to a View Model like "DashboardViewModel" which is composed of different collections which correspond to the data needed for each sub-part. This would also put the aggregation logic to the server-side rather than on the client in JS. You could even have partial views included, each of which corresponds to a sub-part and a collection of data in your View Model. It's good practice to have your view model directly correlate to the data needed by your view